# How would I use regex to store all occurrences of certain words in a document?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm a JavaScript developer who gets weak in the knees when he sees regex.

But right now, I'm working on a side project that seems to require it.

I want to create an array of 'important words' (there are around 250 of them), and then scan through a giant document looking for and storing each occurrence of an 'important word' for analysis and further manipulation.

I have no idea where to start (or what to Google) when it comes to the regex part of this, nor do I know the expertise required for what I'm trying to do.

If I can get the 'important words' individually into an array, I know what to do. It's the steps leading up to that that I'm confused about.

Any basic advice or direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: IndexOf might be a better approach.

Comment: "storing each occurrence" = string index of the starting character of each occurrence of the word? Or do you just want to count the number of occurrences of each word in your search array?

Comment: I want to be able to count the number of occurrences, and also display their values elsewhere. I would be able to do both if I had every occurrence stored as an element in an array

Comment: But the value is just the word; why store the value if they're all the same (since you're testing for words). Just store the count.

Comment: Not necessarily @tenub. If you're using regex to find the words they could all be similar but different.

Comment: Words are words. If you search for a specific word, there can only be one exact match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing something like this?

```
var list = ['test', 'west', 'pest', 'nest'], results = {},
    string = 'pesty test for the pest from the west test';
for (var i=0, l=list.length; i<l; i++) {
    var match = string.match(RegExp('\\b' + list[i] + '\\b', 'gi'));
    results[list[i]] = (match !== null) ? match.length : 0;
}
// results = {test: 2, west: 1, pest: 1, nest: 0}
```